# Why do we abbreviate the Jewish year to the hundreds column?

Tags: minhag, number, calendar, aleph-bet-letters, acronyms

The current Jewish year is 5774 however it is popularly abbreviated as 774 - תשע״ד.
I would like to know why this abbreviation was adopted. I realize that to write out the number 5,000 would require several letters; but then why stop at the hundreds column, why not just '74 - ע״ד instead?

Comment: You'd prefer תתתתתתתתתתתתתתקע"ד? Why stop at the tens column? Why not just ד?

Comment: @DoubleAA 5,000 would be ץץץץץך which is basically the same as the roman numerals for something like 1998 - MCMXCVIII. But whatever the case, how do we know that we can abbreviate in legal documents without affecting their status?

Comment: A) That looks even weirder than what I wrote.  B) That's a completely separate question, which you can ask separately but be sure to provide examples where we do abbreviate. In most Ketubot, for instance, the year is written out in full בשנת חמשת אלפים שבע מאות שבעים וארבע למנין שאנו מונים כאן במי יודע...

Comment: The century (or even millennium) a two digit year is in tends to vary.

Comment: @Danno I have attempted to do so based on your comment. the second question can be found here http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/36698/may-the-jewish-year-be-abbreviated-in-legal-documents

Comment: They used to be space conscious on paper and everything was abbreviated see http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/tagged/acronyms

Comment: @Danno fixed it

Comment: For the same reason everyone doesn't write C.E. after they write a date in 2014? Everyone knows what you mean, why write more. BTW, I have only seen it written ה'תשע"ד, if it is written fully out (or ד, etc. for the appropriate millennium).

Comment: @Deja-jew The usage of ץ as 900 is decidedly non-standard.

Comment: @Ypnypn I only know what wikipedia tells me

Answer (score 3):

I was told that the reason is that since there is no 'thousands' letter equivalent, we tend to show it as a separate indicator. It is similar to people who write the secular year as a two digit rather than a four digit number. Thus, the thousand indicator is shown as the letter with an apostrophe.